# Time required to launch iOS Application

Tags: ios

I want to find the time an iOS Application takes to launch. I tried starting the timer in the viewDidLoad Method and then stoping that timer into ViewDidAppear method. But I am unsure that will give me exact count of time required to launch an iOS Application.

Comment: I would think your app delegate methods, like `application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` would be a better place to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your project's AppDelegate, start the timer on `application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and end it on `application:didBecomeActive:`

According to apple docs:

> **application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:**
>
> > Tells the delegate that the launch process has begun but that state
> >     restoration has not yet occurred.

It's a toss-up (imho) between application:didBecomeActive: and application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:.  You'll have to take a look at the [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiapplicationdelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application%3adidFinishLaunchingWithOptions%3a) to decide.

Using viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear is related to the view controller, and not the application. (Though for practical purposes, these are often very closely related to the AppDelegate methods).

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you can put your first timer in `main.m` as it's the very first entry point in your app, e.g.

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSLog(@"main %f", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]);
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([ZTSAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Finishing is up to your app logic. Sometimes it's `viewDidLoad` of the root view controller, or it might be some point later, after your log in or do all the required initialization steps so app becomes truly responsive.

Comment: okie, basically giving a difference between timestamp is also not bad.